# Sencha Touch history issue, when using routes and route filters

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch 2, I have a beforeFilter, before the routes.

When the user wants to visit a certain view, the "beforeFilter" acts first.

I use the filters for authentication check and other things.
I kept the example very simple, to highlight where I need help:

```
Ext.define("TestApp.controller.Router", {

    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

    config: {
         before: {
            home: 'beforeFilter',
            login: 'beforeFilter',
            products: 'beforeFilter'
        },

        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            'home' : 'home',
            'login' : 'login',
            'products' : 'products',
            'products/:id': 'product',
        }
    },

    beforeFilter: function(action) {

        // The before filter acts before the user gets to any of the routes.

        // Check the user's authentication state.

        // If the user wants to visit the "products" route and he ISNT't authenticated,
        // Redirect the user to the login page.
        this.redirectTo('login');

        // else - go to the normal root.
        action.resume();
    },


    home: function () {
        // This and the functions bellow handle the display of the routes.
    },

    login: function () {
    },

    products: function () {
    }
});
```

The problem.

User wants to view the **products** route but he **isn't logged in.**

The **beforefilter** steps in, and redirects the user to the login page.

Here is where I need help:

If the user is on the login page and clicks a button which triggers Sencha's history.back() event, the user gets redirected to the **products page, AGAIN**, the **beforefilter** steps in, and it **redirects him back to the login view**.

Basically, the history will no longer work.

**To solve the problem**, I would need a way to keep the **products** route from being logged into **Sencha's history object** when the user isn't authenticated.

Do you guys have other ideas?

I asked a more general question about this, but this one feel more documented to the issue in particular.

Comment: Have you tried to manually remove the route from Ext.app.History's stack? That seems like it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For views that you don't want to have history support, simply add / change the view without using `redirectTo`.

Straigh to viewport:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'myloginview'})
```

or with navigation view (in a controller):

```
this.getMyNavView().push({xtype: 'myloginview'})
```

this way the url doesn't change to #login, and doesn't add to the history stack.